# Difference between express.js and axios.js in Node

Tags: node.js, express, http, request, axios

We use axios for http requests such as get, post, etc.
We use express for the same purpose also.
However according to what I read, they are for different purposes.
Please explain how.

PS: If you explain it by giving an example, it would be great!

Comment: Have you read their respective website ?

Comment: express.js is web framework of javascript, but axios.js is Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js. they are do diffrent things

Comment: I suggest you fo through this short description here  - https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/router

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can think of express.js as a warehouse:

```
app.get('/item/:name', async function (req, res) {
  res.send(await findItemByName(req.params.name));
});
```

If you want to get an item, for example a `pencil`, from this warehouse, you can use axios.js.

`axios.get('/item/pencil')`

Comment: We use ajax requests for getting/posting an item. So is axios a way to send them securely?

Comment: ajax and axios do exactly the same thing. axios isn't more secure, but personally I think it's easier to use (less code to write, promise-based,...)

Answer (score 14):

**Axios** is used to **send** a web request whereas **express** is used to **listen and serve** these web requests.

In simple words, express is used to respond to the web requests sent by axios.

If you know about the fetch() method in javascript, axios is just an alternative to fetch().

Answer (score 2):

I would say that express is used to create HTTP servers. So the server runs somewhere and **responds** to a request.

Axios is an HTTP client. It **creates** requests!

Answer (score 0):

In very simple words axios is just passing the web request to the server-side (express). They basically work together (axios -> express -> DB)